# Why does the 'b' in absorb change to a 'p' in absorption?

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, suffixes, latin, consonants

The question pretty much says it all.  Why is "absorbtion" an incorrect spelling?

Comment: Because it was [borrowed like that](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=absorption) from Latin (rather than created from *absorb* and *-tion* in English).

Comment: That is a distinctly unhelpful answer. The real reason has to do with pronunciation, not etymology. Where did the /p/ come from?

Comment: @John Lawler: That certainly rings true to me. I seem to find it difficult to articulate a "b" rather than a "p" in *absorption*. I'm not sure why though - I don't detect any tendency to pronounce *gobshite* as *gopshite*, so it doesn't seem to be just a matter of the following consonant being "sh".

Comment: Being from North America, I don't detect any tendency to pronounce _gobshite_

Comment: @Chris Cudmore: It's one of our secret codewords so we can recognise other Brits!

Comment: Looks like @John and others are completely missing my point. Of course the real reason has to do with pronunciation. Much like with *leaf* vs. *leaves*, which is the same phenomenon. The thing is, in the case of *leaf* vs. *leaves* that phenomenon actually happened in English, while in the case of *absorb* vs. *absorption* it took place in Latin, and English merely borrowed the final result. This question here is about Latin, not English. Off-topic.

Comment: So one must know the etymology of any word before daring to ask about it here? Take note.

Comment: @JohnLawler: No, although etymonline.com is a pretty good resource for etymology questions; the point is that Reg's answer is correct from the point of view of English. Asking further about why it happened in Latin is off-topic.

Comment: Even though the same thing happens, in the same ways, and for the same reasons, in English? gods forbid we might stray from The Topic here. whatever it is.

Comment: @John: yes, do take note. We *absolutely* expect people to do their own research before posting. Which is why the question got closed not as off-topic, but as gen-ref. If you want to keep it open, then edit it into shape first. If you want to ask about the same thing happening in the same ways and for the same reasons in English, then do just that. But as it stands, the question doesn't show any research effort whatsoever. It just asks "Why is 'absorbtion' an incorrect spelling" and leaves it at that. And the answer to that is that the spelling *absorbtion* never existed in the first place.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I agree 100 % with you about The Topic. I felt that way when I joined over a year ago, and it hasn't improved, on the contrary. But I guess it is acceptable if this question gets moved to Linguistics.

Comment: As Neil demonstrates below, this question is way too elementary for Linguistics. But linguistics is simply the science of language, and of English grammar. It's not something different from what's discussed here, just the adult version of what we studied in grade school.

Comment: See also: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/301687/9880

Answer (score 33, accepted):

***[Voicing Assimilation](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/they.html#assimilation)*** is the technical term for what happened here.

In English (and Latin, and most Indo-European languages, among many others), /b/ and /p/ are identical in pronunciation (both are bilabial stops), differing only in their [Voice parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_(phonetics)#English_examples); /b/ is **Voiced**, while /p/ is **Voiceless.**

It is a fact about the human vocal tract that consonant clusters that differ in Voice are difficult to pronounce, because changing from Voiced to Voiceless consonants requires independent movement of the larynx, which can be very hard to switch on and off at the millisecond timing required for consonant clusters.

Therefore there is a universal tendency in human language for consonant clusters to be either all Voiced or all Voiceless. However, what determines voicing when a cluster is formed from two dissimilarly-voiced consonants varies from language to language.

In Russian, for example, it's **Regressive** assimilation -- the Voice parameter of the **final** consonant in a cluster becomes the parameter of the whole cluster. So the Russian preposition *в* /v/ 'in' is pronounced /f/ when its object starts with a voiceless consonant.

English, however, mostly favors **Progressive** assimilation -- that's why the {-Z} suffixes of noun plural, noun possessive, and verb 3sgpresent vary between /s/ and /z/; they take their voicing parameter from the sound that comes **before** them. The {-D} verb past tense suffix varies between /d/ and /t/ in the same way.

Comment: So I shouldn't get too attached to *gobshite* then? In the fullness of time that too will probably become assimilated. Good answer though, even if technically speaking the question could have been ruled "off-topic".

Comment: So, what, the different between "b" and "p" is supposed to have something to do with how the noise is formed in the throat area (in the larynx)?  For me it's purely an airflow thing - "b" builds up pressure behind the lips which stops building the moment the lips are opened, while "p" keeps the airflow going a moment after the lips are opened up.  This answer doesn't seem to make sense.  (US English here, perhaps this is a British English answer?)

Comment: It **is** an airflow thing. To keep the larynx vibrating, air must flow through it continually from the lungs; but since this is a stop consonant the air can't get out. So you can't keep a [b] (or [d] or [g] or any other voiced stop) going long; soon you have to unseal the lips and let the air pressure out. This is not true of [p] (or [t] or [k], the voiceless counterparts of [d] and [g]). They can be kept as long as you like because they don't involve voicing, i.e, continuous airflow.

Comment: @JohnLawler The noise itself comes when the lips are unsealed, but the difference in flow causes the difference between "b" and "p".  I can't keep a "p" noise going as you suggest (although I can do "k", and "t" to a small extent - it mutates into an "s" after a moment).

Comment: Hm... linguistics -- The question itself is innocent, while the answer sounds off-topic. Would make an excellent post on linguistics site, though. Wonder if @Chris Cudmore's is satisfied.

Comment: I just wanted to mention that there´s *something* in what Izkata says: in English, *neither* [p] nor [b] is actually voiced very much in terms of the duration of time while the vocal folds are still vibrating during the closure-- compared to other languages where the "voiced" stops (canonically) have voicing right through the closure. In English, the difference is essentially one of aspiration, not voicing. However...

Comment: ...in terms of how they behave as a *class* of sounds, we might say that English stops still maintain what is essentially a voiced-voiceless distinction, precisely for reasons such as the observation that is the subject of this thread. In other words, our definitions are even a little circular: part of what makes English /b/ a "voiced" consonant is that it induces other consonants in the cluster to be "voiced". But if you look at how much voicing there is during the closure of a typical /b/ in English, you may find there's very little reason for calling it "voiced" phonetically speaking.

Comment: Yes, Neil's right. There's a whole lot more going on in phonation than simply voiced/voiceless. Most of the time English speakers take their cues from the aspiration of voiceless stops, for instance, or on the length of the vowel preceding stops, instead of their voicing value. And quite often voicing is neutralized. This was intended to be a somewhat elementary answer, in keeping with the nature and location of the question.

Comment: @JohnLawler Since you’re talking about assimilation and the reduction of consonant clusters, could you please take a look at [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/110744).  I’m pretty sure you recently answered something like this, although maybe it was in a comment; in any event, I can’t find it. Thanks.

Comment: I saw that and didn't really see anything I could add.

Comment: Ok, thanks. There does seem to be some argument over whether elision and/or assimilation applies here, but I don’t see how you count a glottal allophone of /t/ as an elision myself.

Comment: Who cares what you call it?. The phonetic realities are unchanged.  Terminology is to make things clearer, not to argue about

Comment: @JohnLawler your answer is good, but I really understood it better with the example of descriBe and descriPtion, since the B and P are pronounced distinctly and differently.  But the P is not voiced so much at all with absorPtion and is rather silent, whereas the B in AbsorB is not silent.  Still as a novice writer, I hate learning trivial spelling differences like this, just so I don't sound like an idiot.

Comment: Don't worry about spelling. Pay attention to the **sound** instead. Spelling is for editors and computers. The sounds of the words are what's important to a writer.

Answer (score 12):

The main reason is most likely pronunciation. There is another example of this, where the difficulty may be more prominent: *describe*. It would be rather difficult to say *describtion,* as compared to *description,* which flows off of one's tongue rather nicely. The same goes for *absorption*; it is simply easier than *absorbtion*.

Etymonline suggests that this change occurred in the Latin roots (for both [*absorption*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=absorption) and [*description*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=description&allowed_in_frame=0)). Nowadays, hoi polloi are more eloquent than the commoners who spoke Latin; while we today may not find it difficult to say these, they would have.

Comment: My humor detector might be on the fritz. Is that last sentence a joke, or do you really claim that the Romans had some sort of speech impediment that we don't?

Comment: Also: "cribsheet" is a perfectly pronounceable English word that contains the same consonant cluster as in the hypothetical "describtion".

Comment: Back in the day, many commoners were less educated.

Comment: _Cribsheet_ is an interesting word. It reminded me of _crapshoot_ and -- a new form of seacoast venery -- _crabshoot._ I'd pronounce them differently; or at least I believe I would.

Comment: I think there may be something akin to circular reasoning here. You say **description** *flows off of one's tongue rather nicely* - so by implication, **describtion** doesn't. But it's not obvious to me either is inherently easier or harder to pronounce, except insofar as *we are more used to saying "p" rather than "b" in these contexts*. Per my comment to the question, Brits at least have no problem enunciating *gobshite* with "b" rather than "b" (not would Americans, if they were to adopt the word! :)

Comment: You make a good point, @Fumble.

Comment: How can you say that the Romans were poorly educated? Why, almost all of them spoke Latin!

Comment: Dickensian-type lowly commoners are apt to introduce an extraneous "b" into words like *fambly* and *chimbley*. Perhaps "posh" technical terms like *absorption* get that "p" to distance themselves more from the hoi polloi (aka the great unwashed, who wouldn't know an absorption spectrum from a bathtub ring! :)

Comment: Note that it should be "nowadays, *hoi polloi* are...". It is plural, and the article is already included (so no "the").

Comment: @Cerberus: Stop trying to force people to use Greek rules in English sentences.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 Hey, if that's what's correct, then so be it.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew: People are free to disregard stylistic advice; but I think they should have it, especially if there is some sort of consensus.