# In some parts of America, do people commonly use a flap after /n/, e.g. /ˈwɪn.t̬ɚ/?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, dialects, flapping

I noticed that, in some American dialect (maybe in the South of America), people may use "**flap T**" after "**n**". For example, "`/ˈwɪn.t̬ɚ/`" [source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/winter)

Other example, "**ninety**" `/ˈnaɪn.t̬i/`[Source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ninety)

So, my question is, in some parts of America, *do people there **COMMONLY** use flap T after n*?

Comment: I am not sure about the pronunciation but one thing you'll find in almost every language, especially English is that there is always an exception to a rule. So, as @michael_timofeev says, you might want to change '_always_' to something else.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110741/nt-pronounced-as-n-in-american-english-as-in-internet-what-is-it-called

Comment: A quick link from the other SE article to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_accents_of_English#North_America) offers clues as to locale. Basically it's a North American English thing, but can also be found elsewhere.

Comment: @Nonnal Very relevant and possibly a duplicate: [Does the /d/ in the 'nd' combo tend to be unreleased?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/430290/4972)

Comment: Good contribution to the discussion, @Mitch, even if we did have to wait 2.5 years for it. :-D

Answer (score 1):

Phonetic literature that I have seen typically describes this as a nasal/nasalized tap/flap rather than a nasal consonant followed by a tap/flap.

The frequency of this pronunciation varies by dialect, but I am not aware of any dialect where [nt] with non-flapped t has been completely eliminated. In most dialects, [nt] is a possible realization of /nt/ even before an unstressed syllable.

Comment: It's practically impossible to pronounce a flap immediately after a nasal stop, so I agree with this.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. That 'iz' correct. Consonants may 'be-kome' accentuated and derivative in their common verbal and parochial usage. Like, 'Where'av you been?' or, adding a  hard z - "What iz zat?". The contraction and consonant alteration can almost become another language, but they are not written that way, except to cite accents.

Comment: The only part of this that appears to have anything to do with the question (the first four words) are incorrect. The rest seems like a fairly unrelated rant.