# does the /d/ in the [nd] combo tend to be unreleased?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, north-american-english, consonants

I'm asking about north-American English.

In words like "refu**nd**", "ba**nd**" and "diamo**nd**", is the /d/ is fully released (as an un-aspirated `/d/`), or stopped, like the `/nt/` combo? (different can and usually pronounced as `[dɪfɹənt̚]`)?

Answer (score 1):

The elision of a voiced dental stop in certain environments is not [limited to American English](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=pzze3JfGDoA#), but can be considered an international standard.

Or is that AmE *innernational*? If I strain my memory to produce a context where a *d* is similarly dropped, it would be how Lawrence Welk pronounced his [catchphrase](https://peterkurtz.wordpress.com/tag/lawrence-welk/) "Wonnerful, wonnerful," but he, famously, was not a native speaker, though perfectly capable of pronouncing *wonderful* when [necessary.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=lLW_mumlri4) Otherwise, even those who pronounce *winter* as *winner* will pronounce the *d* in *wander*. The AmE allergy to medially pronounced *t* — so often flapped or elided — does not extend to its voiced twin.

Your examples all have *-nd* in final position, which is fairly protected in most environments except in the conjunction *and*, which prosody can reduce to a mere *n*, and in [AAVE](https://www.hawaii.edu/satocenter/langnet/definitions/aave.html#sounds-hce). One would expect, however, elision for all native speakers when *-nd* is followed by another dental stop:

> We will send your refund to the address you provided.
>
> He's bound to come eventually.

Or even:

> "I assume, my Lord, you have come to bend the knee."

unless, of course, you're [Daenerys Targeryan](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=eUSaWc_aFdo) addressing John Snow with royally crisp consonants.

Other speakers won't likely be quite as fussy, and even Daenerys would need a glottal stop to pronounce every consonant in *bound to*. In the same way, Daenerys might pronounce the plurals

> *refunds, bands, diamonds*

with a non-aspirated *d* but the common folk would simply elide it.

Comment: note I don't ask about *elision* but about *stopping*. if you had to say "this is my band", would you stop your d?

Comment: That's answered when I talk about final position, which goes double for final position in a clause. There is no such thing as an unstopped d, since it's a dental stop. It can be unaspirated in certain environments. Except in assimilated environments (bound to) and with plurals and 3rd p sg (binds = bines) the d is pronounced normally except in AAVE.

Comment: I feel like 'international _standard_' is a bit strong. There's a tendency in certain varieties to do it, as well as the lack of a tendency to do it in others. Like the classic 'water' in AmE is lenited to a flap but is, to my AmE ears, an extra aspirated t in RP.

Comment: @Mitch: the video I linked to is from the BBC Learning English series, which I would consider an authoritative source on BrE.