# Why is it "description" but "describe" (b and p)?

Tags: etymology

I've just wondered by it is "description", but "to describe". It looks as if "to descripe" would be a more consistant choice. Is there any other explanation besides "this is how it is written for years"?

edit: Or alternatively "to describe" and "describtion".

Comment: @DanSheppard Oooops. I've corrected it. Thank you!

Comment: Actually I think it likelier that it was originally "describtion", but "-bt-" is a very rare cluster in English and so it mutated to the easier-to-say "-pt-".

Comment: Latin had _scriba_ ("official writer"), which Merriam-Webster says is the source of _scribe_, and _scriptum_ ("thing written"), which MW says is the source of _script_. So the divergence in _b/pt_ spelling between _scrib_ and _script_ occurred before English came onto the scene.

Comment: Let's see how many more we can think of. I'll start with *absorb* and *absorption*.

Comment: Seems to me that it's pretty standard in L for a voiced stop to devoice or assimilate before a voiceless stop: *agere/actum, ad+tangere>attingere, ad+parere>apparere, ad+capere>accipere*

Comment: @Hellion. It did not happen in English. It happened already in Latin.

Comment: Related: [Why does the 'b' in absorb change to a 'p' in absorption?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59530)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "description (n.) late 14c., from Old French description (12c.) and directly from Latin descriptionem (nominative descriptio) "representation, description, copy," noun of action from past participle stem of describere "write down, transcribe, copy, sketch," from de- "down" (see de-) + scribere "write" (see script (n.)).

and

> "descriptive (adj.) 
>   1751, from Late Latin descriptivus, from descript-, past participle stem of describere (see description). Related: Descriptively; descriptiveness.

and

> "describe (v.) 
>   early 13c., descriven, from Old French descrivre, descrire (13c.), from Latin describere "to write down, copy; sketch, represent" (see description). Reconstructed with Latin spelling 16c. Related: Describable; described, describes, describing."

All from: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=description

Answer (score 2):

The Latin verb forms are scribo, scripsi, scriptum (I write, I have written, written). b before s and t becomes ps and pt because a soft consonant and a hard consonant don't go together well.