# What determines the addition of the suffixes "tion" and "sion"?

Tags: pronunciation

Why does the **B** in the word *absorb* change to **P** when the suffix "tion" is added?

Absorb + tion = absor**p**tion and not absor**b**tion.

The answer to this question is here:

**Question:** [Why does the B in absorb change to a P in absorption?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59530/why-does-the-b-in-absorb-change-to-a-p-in-absorption)

**Answer:** Too long but here is the main part:

> Voicing Assimilation is the technical term for what happened here.

This was an existing question and answer but my question is different from that one so it's not a duplicate.

---

**My question is:**

> *Why does the B change to P in the root word but the suffix remains the same. Why didn't the suffix "sion" attach to the word *absorb*? It could have been *absorbsion*.
>
> If we have to keep the alternating sounds the same, then B and zh (of sion) are both voiced.
>
> In most words, the sounds in the root words remain the same and the suffix is changed.

> Is there any rule that determines the addition of "tion" and "sion"? When should we use "tion" and when "sion"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the 'b' in absorb change to a 'p' in absorption?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59530/why-does-the-b-in-absorb-change-to-a-p-in-absorption)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When are 'tion', 'sion', and 'cion' used](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244078/when-are-tion-sion-and-cion-used)

Comment: [Bottom line:](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/59538/2637) */b/ and /p/ are identical in pronunciation (both are bilabial stops), differing only in their Voice parameter; /b/ is Voiced, while /p/ is Voiceless.* And that very lucid answer from John Lawler on the earlier question clearly explains how the way *English* deals with the inherent "awkwardness" of the situation differs from how it's handled in, say, Russian. Which I assume implies it would be useful for ***learners*** (nns) to know whether ***their*** language favours *Progressive* or *Regressive* assimilation in this context.

Comment: I'm afraid the close voters didn't read the full question. The first one is linked to my question, it didn't answer my question. John Lawler has given an excellent answer but that doesn't say why *absorption* is not *absorbsion*.

Comment: The second one says "*If the ending comes after any consonant apart from -l, -n, or -r, then the ending is spelled -tion: action; connection; reception; affection; interruption; description; collection; infection; deception*" but it doesn't address the change of B to P. So both don't answer my question.

Comment: First, English spelling is arbitrary and represents English pronunciation only by accident. Second, voicing assimilation and palatalization are phonological processes and apply **only** to English pronunciation, not to English spelling. So the questions don't have answers because there is no "why" for arbitrary spellings; they're not decided by [The Academy](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html), but by random people who don't know "why", and don't particularly care.

Comment: **TRADISION!!!!**

Answer (score 2):

The distribution of *-sion* and *-tion* in English is primarily historical, not rule-based: words that were spelled with sio(n) in Latin continue to be spelled with s, while words that were spelled with tio(n) in Latin are spelled with t (in the past, the letter c was a common alternative to t in words like this).

In Latin, *-sio, -sion-* is the form that the suffix *-tio, -tion-* regularly took when it combined with a preceding “dental” consonant (Proto-Indo-European *t, *d or *dh, which generally correspond to Latin t and d). In a few contexts, Proto-Indo-European *dh turned into Latin b, as in *iubeo*, which has a related noun *iussio*. But the b in *absorbeo* does not come from *dh. Since the stem of *absorbeo* never ended in a dental consonant, it isn't expected to take the *-sio* variant of the suffix *-tio.*

The *-sio* variant was expanded to some words that didn’t originally have a dental consonant, but that didn’t happen in the case of *absorptio.*

In English, *-tion* is a more common termination than *-sion*, so there is not much pressure within English to replace *-tion* with *-sion*: in fact, *-tion* spellings have expanded compared to Latin in the case of certain words that originally had *-xio(n)* such as *reflexion* and *connexion*. In terms of phonetics, there are many other words with /pʃ/; e.g. *reception, interception, inscription, corruption;* the same can’t be said for /bʒ/.